# Tracking a specific value with contentOffSet

Tags: ios, contentoffset

I want to change the frame of a view while the user is scrolling. 
I'm checking the contentOffSet of the scroll view in scrollViewDidScroll, and I want to know when the contentOffSet reach a specific value. But I figure out if the user is scrolling faster, that value is skipped.

Do you know a method to track the contentOffSet in a precise way?

Comment: please try this func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(UIScrollView) delegate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to track the scrolling with finer precision.

The best thing to do, would be to check that the `contentOffset` is greater than or less than what you're looking for (depending on the circumstances).

You'd also need a way of checking if the cutoff point had already been reached (so that you didn't execute multiple times).

```
private var triggeredAnimation = false

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !triggeredAnimation, scrollView.contentOffset.y > 100 {
        triggeredAnimation = true
        // Cut off point reached, do whatever you want now
    }
}
```

Of course, if whatever action you're performing is reversible, you'd need to reset when going the other way.